# Why unconstructed object can be passed to base class constructor in derived initialization list

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, initialization-list

I have a class hierarchy, where, in derived class, an object of Dog class is declared. Then, that object is supplied to base class in the initialization list.

Since Dog class object is not constructed before base class constructor is called, so that object should not be of any use. But, I see that, that object can be used in following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Dog {
    public:
        Dog() {cout << "\n In Dog";}
        void dfoo(){cout << "\n In dfoo";};
};

class Foo {
    public:
        Foo(Dog d){cout << "\n In Foo"; 
        d.dfoo();
    }
};

class Bar : public Foo {
    Dog d;
    public:
        Bar() : Foo(d) {
            cout << "\n In Bar";
        }
};

int main() {
    cout << "\nHello";
    Bar b;

}
```

Output is:

`Hello
     In Foo
     In dfoo
     In Dog
     In Bar`

The output shows that dfoo() was called even before Dog object was constructed. How is this working like this? Should not 'd' be junk as this is not initialized before Base constructor is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In practice, your object d contains garbage.

When you pass d (by value), you are implicitly calling the copy constructor for Dog, and making a new object of type Dog by executing the copy constructor on a garbage object of type Dog.

So your question is really: why does the implicit copy constructor of Dog not care that the source object was never constructed.

Since the object doesn't even have any contents, it would be quite a lot of wasted effort for the compiler to make the copy constructor care anything about its source.

I don't know exactly how much of that is undefined behavior (happens to work because implementations are sane) vs. things you may be permitted to do with an unconstructed object.

Consider this version of Dog:

```
class Dog {
    public:
        Dog() {cout << "\n In Dog";}
        Dog(Dog const& source) { cout << "\n Trying to copy a Dog\n"; source.dfoo();}
        virtual void dfoo() const {cout << "\n In dfoo";};
};
```

Now your use of it crashes the way you might have expected (as a result of the source of the copy constructor never having been constructed itself).

Your call to the copy constructor of Dog is hidden inside the action of passing by value to the constructor of Foo.  Notice it happens before the constructor of Foo is actually reached.  That copy construction of Dog (with all its benefits and/or problems) occurs with or without the explicit definition of a copy constructor for Dog.  If you don't define it, the compiler defines it for you.

Comment: How can Foo constructor accept a garbage object when it requires a proper Dog?

Comment: Failing when the programmer did something wrong was never a major design goal of C++.  C++ programs are supposed to work reasonably efficiently when coded correctly.  That expectation of efficiency eliminates most ability to sanity check the programmer's actions.  The Foo constructor does not require a "proper Dog".  It only requires something which you have claimed is a Dog.  Then Dog::dfoo() also only requires something which you have claimed to be a Dog (it doesn't actually use that object in any way).

Comment: Adding a virtual function in Dog class, and calling that on d object from Foo has the same effect. No error.

Comment: Sorry.  I'm so used to passing by reference I failed to notice you had not, which changes the reason all this "works".  I will edit my incorrect answer.

Comment: `@JSF`, No probs. Thanks for elaborating with an example - as expected, that gives a seg. fault. Any suggestion, apart from reference passing, on how to force the language to raise a flag in this type of scenario?

Comment: Did you try the -Wall suggested by Steephen?  The use of that is not limited to Clang.  G++ and other compilers also give you warnings for more coding errors when you use -Wall.  There are also  tools for detecting use of uninitialized memory at run time.  In a non trivial example, I would expect your unconstructed object to have contents copied by the copy constructor (when you pass by value).  Even if those contents ultimately don't matter, the copy action will still be detected as use of uninitialized memory.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, your code is subject to undefined behavior.

You are passing an uninitialized `d` to `Foo::Foo()`. You are not seeing any problems since `Dog` does not have any member variables and `Dog::dfoo()` does not depend on the value of any member variables.

If you add a member variable to `Dog` and use that member variable in `Dog::dfoo()`, you might see strange output:

```
class Dog {
    int v1;
    public:
        Dog() {cout << "\n In Dog";}
        void dfoo(){cout << "\n In dfoo, v1: " << v1 << endl;};
};
```

Comment: Output with your change is:
`
In dfoo, v1: 0
`

Comment: @DKR, unfortunately, that's the nature of undefined behavior. You might see seemingly sane result with one compiler and one setting but that will change with a different compiler and/or different compiler setting.

Comment: If you build it in debug mode, your compiler may initialize all member variables to some default value (e.g., `0`). Try this in release mode.

Comment: @Steve, yes, in release mode the value is garbage.

Comment: @DKR, I am happy to hear that you were able to verify the UB nature of the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you compile your code in clang, you will get warning but you will get the same output.

```
clang++ -std=c++11  -Wall  -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
```

> main.cpp:21:21: warning: field 'd' is uninitialized when used here
>   [-Wuninitialized]     Bar() : Foo(d) {

So what is happening?

You are passing an uninitialized object of Dog as parameter to constructor of Foo. Since your constructor accepting Dog parameter as value, it will try to call the **copy constructor** of class Dog to create an object of Dog even though it is not initialized. And system succeeded to create a local Dog object  using copy constructor inside the constructor of Foo and invoked the function dfoo().

Comment: yes I was expecting that kind of message with g++. Glad that someone is doing that!

Answer (score 0):

It *is* junk.

Not sure what visible symptoms you expected from this, though. For one, `Dog` has no data members.

Comment: I expected some kind of error for 1) passing uninitialized object 2) using that object.

Comment: `@Lightness Races in Orbit` Well, not really, some of them are already fulfilled in the link I mentioned :)